# For which class of functions can we bound the essential supremum of the Hilbert transform?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, transformation, integral-transforms

In [Terry Tao's notes](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/247a.1.06f/notes4.pdf) on the Hilbert transform it is stated that the Hilbert transform is not bounded on the spaces $L^1$ and $L^\infty$. I'm currently working on a problem where it would be convenient to find a bound for $$||H(f)||_{L^\infty}$$ in terms of e.g. a finite sum of $L^p$-norms of $f$, bounds in terms of derivatives of $f$ (if we assume $f$ to be differentiable) etc.

Does someone know such bounds? It would be also interesting to know if we can obtain bounds when restricting our function $f$ to some special class.

Comment: I don't think it need to be the case that $f \in L^p$ implies $Hf \in L^\infty$.